# No known route from 'cmyk' to 'srgb' when processing images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

CodeSandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/jj597mrvmw

I am having an issue with some data returned from an external **API** to my **GatsbyJS/ReactJS** site.

More specifically, the issue appears to be when processing the images with `gatsby-image` and `gatsby-plugin-sharp` using the API `...GatsbyImageSharpFluid` on **GraphQL** queries.

From the 1000's of images, it appears that only 1 is troublesome, returning the error

```
Errors:
  icc_transform: no input profile
  vips_colourspace: no known route from 'cmyk' to 'srgb'
```

I could just filter this image out but am concerned that future images as the API updates could cause the same issue.

**How can I**

1. Fix this error presented by `sharp` so that the image can be processed? or,
2. `filter` image(s) that return this error during processing of the `createRemoteFileNode`, or
3. Skip troublesome image(s) within `catch (error)`, or
4. Any other thoughts/solutions

`createRemoteFileNode` within `gatsby-node.js` is as

```
exports.sourceNodes = async ({ actions, store, cache, createNodeId }) => {
  const { createNode, createNodeField } = actions;
  const { data } = await axios.get(API_URI);

  for (const event of data._embedded.events) {
    let fileNode;
    let output = [];
    let filterResults = event.images.filter(e => e.width >= 1900);
    output.push(...filterResults);
    try {
      fileNode = await createRemoteFileNode({
        url: output[0].url,
        cache,
        store,
        createNode,
        createNodeId,
      });
      await createNodeField({
        node: fileNode,
        name: 'EventImage',
        value: 'true'
      });
      await createNodeField({
        node: fileNode,
        name: 'name',
        value: event.name
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn('error creating node', error);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: be sure to check out the sharp documentation: http://sharp.dimens.io/en/stable/search.html?q=cmyk . however it looks like your troublesome image has the cmyk color space. You could use gimp to change that for this particular image and see if it works.

Comment: Cheers, been there but unfortunately it is a troublesome image. I have filtered the image out but the issue lies in whether more come from the API. I need a solution to `catch` and skip these images but cannot understand how to identify the error prior to the `build` failing.

Comment: As you have probably discovered by now, this is likely a [bug in Gatsby](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/10040) or a [regression in Sharp](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/99), but the bigger problem is that Gatsby has no effective error handling for these kinds of situations. You might try opening a feature request for that, too, but it is not obvious what to do when you ask for a transformed image and you cannot get one.