# How to set background-size: contain on Gatsbys Plugin "gatsby-remark-images"

Tags: gatsby

I'm using `gatsby-transformer-remark` to render images with markdown in my GatsbyJs Blog.

Im using following configuration in my gatsby-config.js file:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
  options: {
    plugins: [
      {
        resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
        options: {
          maxWidth: 500,
          wrapperStyle: `text-decoration: none; background-image: none;`,
          quality: 75,
          showCaptions: true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

I have images which are 3x higher than they are wide. This way, they take up too much space.

When I add a `maxHeight` property, I'll get a cropped result - instead I'd like to have a contained result as with CSS:

> background-size: contain;

I figured out that this plugin takes the same parameters as `gatsby-plugin-sharp` but even there I couldn't find a way to render the images in a contained fashion.

Comment: Does `object-fit: contain` on the `prop` `imgStyle` apply the change you need. I just tested here and it took the default `object-fit: cover` to `contain.

Comment: What does your query look like? If you're using `sizes` and specifying the width and height you will get an image that should match those dimensions. If you're using `fluid` you should be setting a `maxWidth` or `maxHeight` (usually in the query, not the config) and you'd let that dictate your max size. You can also always use custom styles to adjust the use, or roll your own component to consume the `srcSet` generated by `gatsby-plugin-sharp`.

Comment: @coreyward There is no need for a query - the plugin renders images so that I can reference them in my markdown files (see: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-remark-images/ ). This is why it is not feasible to use these parameters you suggested.

Comment: @InsOp Ah, I had totally missed the `gatsby-remark-images` name in your config. 

Answer (score 1):

I often find myself in the same situation with `gatsby-image`.

The way I personally handle this is by using CSS and adding `object-fit` as `contain` on `img` wrapped in `gatsby-image-wrapper`. This will contain the image to the height or width of the containing element.

```
.gatsby-image-wrapper img {
   object-fit: contain !important; // !important to override the element style
}
```

One thing you'll also want to ensure is that the elements wrapping `gatsby-image` have a `position: relative` or a fixed size as to stop any `overflow` of the image.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice workaround, but I cannot mark this as the solution, since I'm convinced that there must be an official solution to this. We cant be the only ones struggling with this are we?

Comment: I agree, however, I never found any documentation or previous questions regarding the topic. This for me works 90% of the time for the projects I have... the rest of the time I'll go old school using `CSS` and media queries to deliver sized images. I'm currently having `gatsby-plugin-sharp` issues myself here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53340007/no-known-route-from-cmyk-to-srgb-when-processing-images... you ever come across this?